# Use std algorithm to remove objects from a container

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, stl-algorithm

Suppose I have an `std::unordered_set` storing objects of class `A`. Now I would like to remove a subset of objects that satisfy a given `condition` and apply another function to each object in the subset. What is the best (or elegant) way to do this?

One possible solution can be:

```
std::unordered_set<A> myset;

//.. initialize data

std::for_each(myset.begin(), myset.end(), [](A&) { if(condition(A)) { /*do something on A*/} });

auto itrs = std::remove_if(myset.begin(), myset.end(), [](A&) {return condition(A)});
myset.erase(itrs, myset.end());
```

Obviously the above solution requires two-step function calls. Is there any way to simplify this?

Comment: I was about to suggest to do your stuff in the predicate of `remove_if`. But you can't. Would have been so easy ...

Answer (score 4):

Start with writing an algorithm to erase based on a predicate from an associative container (erase/remove-if doesn't work for `unordered_set`):

```
template <class Container, class Predicate>
void erase_if(Container& c, Predicate pred)
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    auto first = begin(c);
    auto last = end(c);
    while (first != last) {
        if (pred(*first)) {
            first = c.erase(first);
        }
        else {
            ++first;
        }
    }
}
```

And then just pass in a predicate that both checks your condition and then does some operation:

```
erase_if(myset, [](A const& a) {
    if (condition(a)) {
        /* do something */
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```